# добавление случайного значения в список

Tags: python, list, двумерный-массив

каким образом в список [j] закладывается случайное значение, когда мы даем его только для [i]?

```
from random import randint
print('Программа формирования матрицы случайных целых двузначных чисел')
n = int(input('Введите количество строк матрицы -> '))
m = int(input('Введите количество столбцов матрицы -> '))
print('Сформированная матрица:')
matrix = []
# Создаем матрицу n X m и выводим на экран
for i in range(n):
    matrix.append([])
    for j in range(m):
        matrix[i].append(randint(10,99))
        print(matrix[i][j], end = ' ')
    print()
```

Comment: Что называется бьюсь об заклад, в строке matrix[i].append(randint(10,99)) мы вкладываем значения только для индексов [i], но как рандомные значения получают [j] ?

Comment: В строке `matrix[i].append(randint(10,99))` **создаётся** это самое значение для j путём добавления нового элемента в массив `matrix[i]`

Comment: Ну а `matrix[i][j]` это вообще не массив, а число (созданное через этот самый randint)

Comment: создаётся это самое значение для j путём добавления нового элемента в массив matrix[i]
как?

Comment: А что делает append?

Comment: добавляет в массив matrix[i] значение

Comment: В список, ну да ладно. И какие индексы имеет последний добавленный элемент?

Comment: В  "список [j]" никаким образом ничего не добавляется, потому что [j] это вообще не список.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю вы имели ввиду как в списке i по индексу j появляются числа потому что значение по индексу i и j это число. Если так, то вы в начале первого цикла создаете и добавляете пустой массив после чего в следующем цикле обращаясь к нему по индексу добавляете значения и под конец второго цикла у вас получается заполненный массив(строка).

Comment: значения добавляются не по индексу, а в конец списка. Просто тут в коде так совпало, то текущий индекс конца списка равен j.

Comment: Я знаю, я имел ввиду к массиву по индексу, но и хотя с другой стороны также можно сказать что он берет просто последний массив